# Insert into Ajax php

Tags: php, ajax

Hello i need help in this code,i am new in ajax and php. this code dont work and idk why.
I want insert the form on database without refresh.
here is the code

All html of the site with the script
Im using boostrap

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CS INICIO</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #13171a">
<div class="container container-table">
    <div class="row vertical-center-row">
    <div class="text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <form id="formulario"  method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name= "nome" required="true" placeholder="Nome">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name= "link" required="true" placeholder="Link Steam">
            <select class="form-control" name="rank">
                <option value="silver1">Silver 1</option>
                <option value="silver2">Silver 2</option>
                <option value="silver3">Silver 3</option>
                <option value="silver4">Silver 4</option>
                <option value="silver5">Silver Elite</option>
                <option value="silverElite">Silver Elite Master</option>
                <option value="silverEliteMaster">Silver 1</option>
                <option value="goldnova1">Gold Nova 1</option>
                <option value="goldnova2">Gold Nova 2</option>
                <option value="goldnova3">Gold Nova 3</option>
                <option value="goldnovamaster">Gold Nova Master</option>
                <option value="ak1">Master Guardian 1</option>
                <option value="ak2">Master Guardian 2</option>
                <option value="akcruzada">Master Guardian Elite</option>
                <option value="eximio">Eximio</option>
                <option value="le">Legendary Eagle</option>
                <option value="lem">Legendary Eagle Master</option>
                <option value="supreme">Supreme</option>
                <option value="global">Global Elite</option>

    </select>
    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="addData()" id="submit">Button</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addData() {
        dataString = $("#formulario").serialize();
        $(".text-danger").hide();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "enviar.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(resp){
                if(resp.status == '0') {
                    alert("insert error");

                } else {
                        clearInput();
                     alert("insert success");
            }

}
        });

        return false;  //stop the actual form post !important!
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the enviar.php i dont know here is the error
Im new in code
ficheiro php

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
  $host = "localhost";
  $root = "root";
  $pass = "";
  $tabela = "cssite";
  $conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $root, $pass, $tabela) or die("Erro Na base de dados") ;


mysqli_connect_error($conexao);
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $link = $_POST['link'];
    $rank = $_POST['rank'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO utilizadores('nome','rank','link') VALUES ('".$nome."','".$rank."','".$link."')";

    $sql_result = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
    if ($sql_result) {
        echo  1;
    }
    else{
        echo 0;
    }


?>

Thanks all for the help
```

dsadsasafsafasfas

Comment: Your SQL code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: im new in this, how can i fix?

Comment: Google "SQL injection", theres tonnes of guides on what it is, and how to fix it.

Comment: would you try self test method
first way chrome F12 button developer mode confirm
second way javascript console.log use

Answer (score 0):

Need to change you data object to use curly brackets, not normal ones:

```
data:{nome:nome,link:link,rank:rank},
```

Also need to change your condition in the success callback to a comparison operator as opposed to an assigned operator:

```
if (value == 1) {
```

In your PHP, you need to change `return 1;` and `return 0;` to `echo 1;` and `echo 0;` if you want them to output to the page.

You are also only listening for the click event, you should listen for the submit event so you can prevent the default action. Change:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
```

To:

```
$('#yourform').on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevents submission of the form through normal means.
```

Comment: The three things I provided are issues in your script you need to fix. You have not provided enough detail for me to help you any further than what I've given you.

Comment: i want insert the text of the form in the database without refresh

Comment: Yes , I figured. But you have not told anyone the details of the issue. All you've said is "it's not working".

Comment: i submit the form and nothing happens

Comment: Still doesn't help. Need details, for example: error messages in client console, error messages for PHP, etc.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in the data

Comment: Have you changed the code as I suggested? Is the data object using curly braces? Because you wouldn't be getting that error if you did. Ensure you saved the file and your webserver is serving you the updated file.

Comment: Have you changed `return 1;` and `return 0;` to `echo 1;` and `echo 0;`, because return won't output anything to the page itself. If you are still getting 0 outputted by the PHP script, your insert is failing, possibly due to a bad connection or malformed query.

Comment: Then you have an issue with your PHP script. Probably failing to connect to mysql. You can use `mysqli_connect_error()` to determine if there is an error.

Comment: $conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $root, $pass, $tabela) or die("Erro Na base de dados") ;


mysqli_connect_error($conexao);
 $nome = $_POST['nome'];
 $link = $_POST['link'];
 $rank = $_POST['rank'];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO utilizadores('nome','rank','link') VALUES ('".$nome."','".$rank."','".$link."')";

 $sql_result = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
 if ($sql_result) {
  echo  1;
 }
 else{
  echo 0;
 }

Comment: I can't help you anymore. You need to echo the result of `mysqli_connect_error()` if you want to be able to read it, it won't just output by itself.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: nome in C:\xampp\htdocs\SiteCS\enviar.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: link in C:\xampp\htdocs\SiteCS\enviar.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: rank in C:\xampp\htdocs\SiteCS\enviar.php on line 13

Answer (score 0):

This would help in the "Undefined index error":

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Call this function on button click   
 function addData() {
        dataString = $("#formulario").serialize();
        $(".text-danger").hide();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "enviar.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(resp){
                if(resp.status == '0') {
                    alert("insert error");

                } else {
                        clearInput();
                     alert("insert success");

            }


        });

        return false;  //stop the actual form post !important!
    }
```

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: plz upload your view